# How to fix production 404 error on images' imports

Tags: reactjs, image, vite, vercel

I have a few images on a site that doesn't get loaded. I'm using Vercel and Vite's production preview and both give me this error when importing images:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

And, when I reload the page with the browser console open:

> GET https://nicole-tongu.vercel.app/src/assets/images/nicole_pic.jpeg
> 404

Here's how I have been importing them:

```
<div className="ms-3 home-image-container">
    <img
       src="/src/assets/images/nicole_pic.jpeg"
       className="home-image"
     ></img>
</div>
```

When running the code locally, all images' imports work, but I don't know how to make them appear on production.

You can see all my code on [GitHub](https://github.com/mean-li/nicole-tongu) and the app can be found on [Vercel](https://nicole-tongu.vercel.app/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I fixed it in and I sent out a `pull request` to your
> github. you can [visit the result here](https://nicole-tongu-git-fork-diercohen-bugfix-fix-loading-image-meanli.vercel.app/)

details:

I pull your repository, and run `npm run dev`... it works well. image loaded.
but when I build your app(`npm run build`) and run `npm run preview` to show the built version of your app, it doesn't work(the image doesn't show in browser like vercel). why? because there was no image in `dist` directory.

to load images in `vite` build version, you should have imported them in the header of your `home.jsx` like this:

```
import CallButton from '../components/CallButton'
import '../assets/styles/home.css'

// add this one in your header
import NicoleImage from '../assets/images/nicole_pic.jpeg'

function Home() {
  return (
    <section
      id="home"
      className="bg-primary text-dark p-5 d-flex caixa-responsiva align-items-center"
    >
.
.
.
//rest of your code
.
.
.
```

and after that, you should inject `NicoleImage` variable to your `src` attribute of your `<img` tag, like this:

```
          <img
            src={NicoleImage}
            className="home-image"
          />
```

to sure that it works, run `npm run build` and see that image file is exist in `dist` directory, and for seeing the result, run `npm run preview` command to sure it works on the production

after these steps, you can deploy it on `vercel`

good luck